# How do you specify external configuration in JBoss AS 7?

Tags: deployment, configuration, jboss7.x

We're in the process of upgrading from JBoss Application Server 5.1 to AS 7.  In AS 5.1 we defined a Properties object in a '-service.xml' file so that we could externalize all of our configuration.  We then read this properties object in via JNDI.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr" name="jboss.apps:name=myProperties">
        <attribute name="BindingsConfig" serialDataType="jbxb">
            <jndi:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
                    xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">
                    <jndi:binding name="myConfig">
                            <java:properties xmlns:java="urn:jboss:java-properties"
                                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                    xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:java-properties resource:java-properties_1_0.xsd">
                                    <java:property>
                                     ...
```

What's the appropriate way to do this in AS 7?

Comment: you can do that via putting properties-service.xml in $JBOSS_HOME//standalone/deployments

Comment: Ok, I can put my -service.xml files there and JBoss does attempt to deploy them, but apparently the schemas and class names have all changed.  In particular, the JNDIBindingServiceMgr is missing.

Answer (score 0):

It is explained here: https://community.jboss.org/message/641742#641742

Seems it is possible from AS 7.1, not in 7.0. Didn't try it yet, though.